# Minecraft Adventure maps 1.10 , Commands, Testfor items in dispensers and air

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do you test whether a particular item is a dispenser?

For example, I want to be able to test if a dispenser contains a piece of Stone with the name *key*, and then use that to open a door.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `/testforblock` command for this, which has the syntax:

```
/testforblock <x> <y> <z> <TileName> [dataValue] [dataTag]
```

So to test if it contains stone called "key", you should do:

```
/testforblock X Y Z dispenser -1 {Items:[{id:"minecraft:stone",tag:{display:{Name:"key"}}}]}
```

Comment: ok, thanks, and I want to ask then how do I make the items in the dispenser delete?

Comment: @JarKofolaPetruž Try `/blockdata X Y Z {Items:[]}`

Comment: I forgot for detecting items that only one key, not two, because I do not make a player to lose a key.

Comment: @JarKofolaPetruž I'd use a hopper filter for that then, setblock a hopper below the dispenser then delete it after a delay just long enough for one item.

Comment: - The option b)? I do not know how the use of b) and from testforblock detects items but if there is only one item that will be activated but if there are two so it will not be active. ??

Comment: @JarKofolaPetruž If you only want to only activate when there's a single key in the dispenser, do: `/testforblock X Y Z dispenser -1 {Items:[{id:"minecraft:stone",Count:1b,tag:{display:{Name:"key"}}}]}`

Comment: @JarKofolaPetruž No problem, click the tick to the left of the answer if it answered your question.

Answer (score -1):

if you have only pieces of stone labled key in there you can then send a redstone output of 2 "key put in 23 items" use a comparator to give the signal strengeth of 2